# QGLFramebufferObject floating point texture

Tags: qt, opengl, floating-point, fbo

I need to render to a framebufferobject with GL_FLOAT as internal format for floating-point computations. I know how to achieve this using native OpenGL calls, such as:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height,
             0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

In order to use [QPainter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QPainter.html) to render to a FBO, [QGLFramebufferObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglframebufferobject.html) is required.
However, QGLFramebufferObject doesn't allow to set the type, only the internal format and format of the texture (that is used in an color-attachment in my case).

**Is there any way of using floating-point precision with QGLFramebufferObject in Qt 4.8?**

I know I could somehow patch and recompile Qt, but that's cumbersome and not very elegant.
I also considered writing my own FramebufferObject class, but then one has to derive from QPaintDevice and with that provide a custom QPaintEngine. Not a good solution, as Qt obviously has a paintengine for that, but it's not accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internal format is the *only* thing that makes a texture floating-point. For example:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height,
         0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

This is *not* a floating-point texture. It is a 8-bit-per-component unsigned normalized texture. Because that's what [`GL_RGBA8`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format) means.

So just set the internal format of the `QGLFramebufferObject` to be one of the available floating-point formats.

Comment: Thank's so much! This wasn't clear from the opengl documentation.